# docker-compose fails on RUN sudo gem update --system

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Installed docker desktop for windows in a Hyper-V VM running Windows 10 21H2.  Have cloned a repository from GitHub using the GitHub desktop.  Started a PowerShell as administrator, navigated to the cloned repository location.  When I run docker-compose up I get the following error:

### [+] Building 3.7s (5/9)
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/circleci/ruby:2.7.5-node                                                3.3s
=> CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/circleci/ruby:2.7.5-node@sha256:23d760208eed58ff57f8721d20dcd8c9bc5f9ee8a5293fa14  0.0s
=> ERROR [2/6] RUN sudo gem update --system                                                                       0.2s

> [2/6] RUN sudo gem update --system:
> #0 0.197 sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

---

failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sudo gem update --system]: exit code: 1

docker itself installed ok and is running.  I've checked all the pre-reqs and can see no reason why this is happening.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I can at least say that `sudo` in Docker is almost never necessary, and most configurations of it I've seen don't meaningfully add any security.  Are you already `USER root`; can you just remove `sudo` from the command?  Do you have a [mcve] beyond just this error message?

Comment: Hi David - not really, it's not my container, i'm trying to compile the Australian DTA blueprint container, so I don't know where the sudo command is coming from.  Also, it's docker for windows so no root but I am running the command as a local administrator.